# Update query that needs to find the 'newest' row

Tags: php, sql, mysql, kohana-3

My logout function needs to update the latest row of a list of logins.

This is what I have came up with, however it doesn't even pass syntax validation.

```
$query =
    'UPDATE user_logins
     SET active = 0
     WHERE user_id = ' . Database::instance()->escape($this->getCurrentUserId()) . '
     AND datetime = MAX(datetime) LIMIT 1';
```

Essentially there may be 30 or so with the same `user_id` value. I'd only like to update the last login. This will obviously be the most recent `datetime` value.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This would take like 10 seconds without a framework. They must be fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, provided your datetime column is a `timestamp` or a `datetime` type field.

```
$query =
    'UPDATE user_logins
     SET active = 0
     WHERE user_id = ' . Database::instance()->escape($this->getCurrentUserId()) . '
     ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 0,1';
```

Comment: +1 for speed. Dang. I'll delete my duplicate answer, and learn to type faster :)

Answer (score 0):

<s>You would have to use a subquery for this.</s>

```
$query =
    'UPDATE user_logins
     SET active = 0
     WHERE user_id = ' . Database::instance()->escape($this->getCurrentUserId()) . '
     AND datetime = (SELECT MAX(datetime) FROM user_logins WHERE user_id = '' . Database::instance()->escape($this->getCurrentUserId()) . ') LIMIT 1';
```

Or something like this.

**Edit:**
As the comment states, this will not work because of lack of support in MySQL. I'll leave this answer for the reference.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work with MySQL. You'll get an error `Error 1093 (ER_UPDATE_TABLE_USED)` (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-errors.html)

Comment: In the subquery you also need to add the user id condition, otherwise you will get the maximum datetime from anyone not the current user.

Comment: Hmm, mysql still has a lot to add.

Comment: this approach really seems overkill to me. Why not simply sort the column by datetime first, then select the topmost row as my solution proposes?